# Call action method with Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I tried the solution below without success. In the controller method `MvcAction`, the `prs` parameter is always null. Below is the code I'm using to call the controller method.

```
function getPerson() {
    var jFirstName = '@Model.Person.FirstName';
    var jLastName = '@Model.Person.LastName';
    return { FirstName: jFirstName, LastName: jLastName };
}

var person = getPerson();
var jsonPerson = JSON.stringify(person);

$.post( '@Url.Action("MvcAction", "MvcXontroller")', { prs : jsonPerson },
function( data ) {
    ....
});
```

The action method look like this:

```
public void MvcAction(Person prs)
{

}
```

Comment: If you use Fiddler or a similar tool, what do you see being passed in the body of the `$.post` action?  Please post the body of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `data` null or are you getting 404 errors because the routing engine can not find the `MvcAction` method?

My guess is that since your return type is `void`, the result will always be null. Change your return type to `JsonResult` or something like it if you want to return data back to the client.

*UPDATE*

Try updating your `$.post()` call like this:

```
$.post( '@Url.Action("MvcAction", "MvcXontroller")', JSON.stringify({ prs : person}),
    function( data ) {
        ....
    });
```

Also verify before the `$.post` call that person is a valid jason object with values in First and Last name.

Comment: In the real code is not void, but it's not imporant if I do Console.WrtileLine(prs); I'd like prs not null.

Comment: Are you saying that in the controller method `MvcAction`, `prs` is always null? I'm just trying to fully understand your question.

Comment: Yes null always. It's not clear ? I'm in a view I get 2 values from my Model and with this 2 values (FirstName,LastName), need to create a type (Person) to send a argument to my action

Comment: What does `person` look like after you call `getPerson()`? Does it have values in both `FirstName` and `LastName`? Also while you're at it, update the question and include the code for the `Person` object.